# HTML Parsing Error in IE8: Unable to modify parent container element before the child element is closed

Tags: internet-explorer, parsing, internet-explorer-8, load

I have [this page](http://salliannputman.com/) working fine in Chrome, IE9, Firefox and Safari, but in IE8 the page won't load and I get the following error message:

> HTML Parsing Error in IE8: Unable to modify parent container element
>   before the child element is closed (KB927917).

Could someone please let me know what might be causing this error.

Comment: I don't get this error message in IE8 on Vista (64-bit) - instead, I get Webpage error details
Message: 'undefined' is null or not an object
Line: 22
Char: 16
Code: 0
URI: http://salliannputman.com/js/backgroundPosition.js

When mousing over your menu.

Comment: @dash Thanks for the info.  I have now updated the backgroundPosition.js to the latest version. Could you let me know if you are still seeing the same error in IE8, as I am still seeing the Parsing Error when testing in IE8 using IETester

Comment: I no longer see the error when mousing over the Work menu (although the effect is a little jerky but this is probably due to Terminal Services). Looks fine to me with IE8.

Comment: @dash Thanks for letting me know.  As well as the Parsing Error I am also seeing this "An error has occurred on the script on this page, Line:18 Char:2 Object Required  Code:0" with no more details, and then nothing loads on the page at all.  I am running this within IETester using Parallels on a Mac (Windows 7), so this might be part of the problem.  I'll try and get on to a native Windows PC and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I now think the original error issue was due to IETester and I have switched to another method of testing older versions of IE

Comment: "switched to another method" ... i burn to know which method. IETester doesn't let debug script... or at least, not for me.

Comment: I am testing via a Mac and installed various virtual versions of Windows/IE using Virtualbox